# Dart templates not seen in new Dart project

Tags: dart, webstorm

I am trying to use Webstorm for my Dart project since it is recommended. I have installed it and point it to the Dart sdk and dartium path. On creating a new Dart project, I only see Dart Web App and Dart Command Line App. No polymer template or any other template. What can I do to see those template.

RELEVANT VERSIONS OF DART OFFERINGS:

Dart 1.11.0 (ref 65704b3) DEV (SDK)
Dart 1.11.0 (ref 65704b3) (STABLE) DARTIUM

### EDIT 1 (relates to first comment by Gunter)

I deleted and attempted to reinstall stagehand but I am getting the following errors

```
C:\Users\dart.user\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\global_packages>pub global ac
tivate stagehand
Resolving dependencies...
+ args 0.13.2
+ collection 1.1.1
+ crypto 0.9.0
+ http 0.11.2
+ http_parser 0.0.2+7
+ path 1.3.5
+ source_span 1.1.2
+ stack_trace 1.3.3
+ stagehand 0.2.1
+ string_scanner 0.1.3+1
+ usage 1.0.0+1
Precompiling executables...
Loading source assets...
Failed to precompile stagehand:stagehand:
Unhandled exception:
Uncaught Error: Failure getting http://localhost:49681/packages/crypto/crypto.da
rt: 404 Not Found
Stack Trace:
#0      _asyncLoadError (dart:_builtin:285)
#1      _httpGet.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (dart:_builtin:228)
#2      _RootZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1082)
#3      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone.sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.
dart:390)
#4      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:399)

#5      _BufferingStreamSubscription._close (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:290)
#6      _ForwardingStream._handleDone (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:112)
#7      _handleDone (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:180)
#8      _RootZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1082)
#9      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone.sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.
dart:390)
#10     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:399)

#11     _DelayedDone.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:614)
#12     _StreamImplEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:711)
#13     _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart
:671)
#14     _asyncRunCallbackLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41)
#15     _asyncRunCallback (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:48)
#16     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:84)
#17     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dar
t:131)

#0      _rootHandleUncaughtError.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:886)
#1      _asyncRunCallbackLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41)
#2      _asyncRunCallback (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:48)
#3      _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:84)
#4      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dar
t:131)
```

Several attempts simply result in the same error.

I did a pub cache repair but the result is the same.

Comment: WebStorm uses Stagehand https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stagehand for project templates, maybe you need to activate it first `pub global activate stagehand` (never used it from WebStorm myself yet)

Comment: Stagehand is already activated.

Comment: Stagehand only had an empty bin directory. I attempted activation but receive the errors shown in EDIT 1 of the question above.

Comment: Can you try deactivate and then activate again? I had a similar issue recently and I think this fixed it.

Comment: I simply change the folder in which I placed the dart-sdk and this solved the problem. I can't explain it either. Probably there was a cache some where.

Comment: @st_clair_clarke you should answer your own question then

Answer (score -1):

Stagehand provides the following templates; polymer isn't one of them.

```
$ stagehand
Stagehand will generate the given application type into the current directory.

usage: stagehand <generator-name>
    --[no-]analytics    Opt out of anonymous usage and crash reporting.
-h, --help              Help!
    --version           Display the version for stagehand.
    --author            The author name to use for file headers.
                        (defaults to "<your name>")

Available generators:
  console-full   - A command-line application sample.
  package-simple - A starting point for Dart libraries or applications.
  server-shelf   - A web server built using the shelf package.
  web-angular    - A web app with material design components.
  web-simple     - A web app that uses only core Dart libraries.
  web-stagexl    - A starting point for 2D animation and games.
```